# Intelli-J can't run spock tests? (Unable to attach test reporter...)

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

I'm trying to use the grails spock plugin with 1.3.7. I can run tests from the terminal via `grails test-app :spock`, but when I try to run ControllerSpec tests from within Intelli-J, I get `unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly`.

Has anyone run grails spock test successfully through Intelli-J?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes I have and I have no problems with it. The only thing to remember is that when you right-click your Spec class, to select the right intelliJ runner. So:

1. Right click class
2. Run
3. Select the jUnit icon, NOT the grails icon

Answer (score 0):

When I run into this error message (... unable to attach test reporter ...) I usually have a Groovy syntax error somewhere which isn't shown as such by IntelliJ. This is the downside of Groovy's extreme syntactical flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem "unable to attach test report to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly".

It was happened because my jUnit *.groovy class was in folder \com\myproject\app but in this class the package was set like "package com.myprojec.app.subpacakge". As you may see, package and folder value was different and I broke convention.

When I checked and corrected class' package and folder I saw green tests.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. The cause turned out to be that the class name differed from the filename. I accidently renamed the class without changing the filename (probably forgot to use the rename function of IntelliJ?)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the answer is relevant but this will occur in Intellij. I got the same problem when I switched back to `JUnit` framework from `TestNG`.

I have solved it very easily by following these steps

```
1. Select the class file
2. From Top Menu Panel Click Run > Edit Configurations
3. Select the framework which you want.
```

In my case I have selected the `JUnit` and the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

(My experience in grails 2.4.5)

For those who come across this question and are still stuck I thought I'd mention a gotcha that is easy to miss if you don't create your tests via command line.

It appears that Spock test files (*and* their class names) must be suffixed with the word "Spec".

for Example, in `FakeControllerSpec.groovy`:

```
...
@TestFor(FakeController)
class FakeControllerSpec extends Specification {
...
}
```

If at this point intellij has convinced itself that your test is a junit test (or some  framework other than Spock) you'll need to delete the configuration from `Run > editConfigurations` before you run the test again.