# Spock unit tests in grails for individual test does not work in intellij

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, intellij-idea, spock

I am trying to run individual spock unit tests using intellij idea.

Consider:

`// rest of code
def "Test Something"() {
  // test code below
}`

In above test, when I goto the test body and right context menu, I get two kinds of tests for `Test Something`. One is the grails test and other is the junit test.

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9945308/1291122) question, the accepted answer recommends using the jUnit runner. But using it, the code simply does not compile(probably because certain plugins and other classes are not available).

(I am not sure though as this is the desired behavior because I am just running a **single** test and not all tests. So wonder why is it compiling all classes ,including plugin classes not required by the test target class.)

Using the grails runner, I check the configuration and here is the screenshot:
[image]

So nothing looks wrong with the command there.

But the test on running gives `Test framework quit unexpectedly` error.

I try running same command from grails console(CMD windows) and it runs without any error message.

But on checking the output html files(in target/test-reports) I see that none of the tests actually ran!

So what is going on here and why are not individual tests running?

PS:

When I run All tests using `test-app` command, tests run as expected. Only individual (unit)tests are not running.

Comment: Umm... what grails version, Intellij version, etc?  I run Spock Unit Tests all the time in IntelliJ 2016.1, Grails 2.4.5. Right-click in test method, and choose to run the Grails version. Test configuration looks to be formatted the same as yours.

Comment: I use quote only on the test name. Rest looks fine to me.

Comment: @railsdog I am on intellij 15.0. I think this same configuration used to work all the time for me. But now on its not at all working for any tests in this application! Seems a weird issue to me. Also since grails cmd is also not running individual test, it is possible that the issue may be with grails or my code somewhere itself!

Comment: @Mamun this is by default from intellij.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the price paid for Spock's nice test naming, is that you can't specify an individual test to run anymore.

Here are some articles about it. The first seems pretty on-point:
[Run a specific test in a single test class with Spock and Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031820/run-a-specific-test-in-a-single-test-class-with-spock-and-maven)

This one isn't about running a single test, but has some relevance and talks about Spock's test-name conversions, plus Peter Niederwieser chimes in with comments:
[Can TestNG see my Spock (JUnit) test results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633743/can-testng-see-my-spock-junit-test-results/22788672#22788672)

A workaround for this could be the `@IgnoreRest` annotation.  Simply annotate the test you want to run with `@IgnoreRest`, and then specify that test class to run, and only the annotated test will run.  http://spockframework.github.io/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/IgnoreRest.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the grails unit test and add the following in the command line part:

**-Dgrails.env=development**

This will run the test as we change the running environment to development . Hope this will help to everyone facing such problems.